NTC inrush current limiter steady current rating
I understood most of parameters to choose NTC inrush current limiter, but couldn't understand steady current concept. In particular, how voltage comes into play.
For NTC to work as designed it has to heat up and its high initial resistance drops to nearly 0 Ω allowing full current to pass through. From my understanding of electricity, heat is proportional to power, but power proportional to both current (I) and voltage (U), i.e. P=U*I
I can place NTC before switching power supply that connected to 240 V AC, or I can place NTC before DC-DC switching converter that works from 12 V DC.
For the same power, at different voltage it will be different current. NTC with steady current of 5 A at 240 V has to allow 240x5=1080 W, but same 5 A at 12 V will be only 12x5=60 W.
The small wattage at 12 V will not allow NTC to heat up properly for its resistance to drop and it will stay at much higher resistance than it should.
So, my question is, at what voltage NTCs are rated? And what current should I use if I want to use NTC at 12 V?

Do you understand why we use an NTC thermistor in series with the input to a power converter?

@Andyaka Of course I do, it is capacitive load because it has a capacitor(s) at front stage that are fully discharged, this cause an in-rush current at cold start.

NTCs for current limiting have two ratings. The current needed to keep them 'on', and the voltage they can withstand when limiting or 'off'.
The two are not directly related, except that an NTC with a higher voltage breakdown may tend to be a higher resistance generally, so will need less current to stay hot.
You therefore need to choose a current limiter according to both specifications independently. The withstanding voltage should be at least that of your supply. The maintaining current should be less than your load current.
There are some additional checks you need to do.
You should check that your load will 'start up' if supplied with a low initial voltage from the NTC. Passive loads will, smart loads may not.
You should check your NTC has a sufficient energy rating to avoid overheating during the startup surge. As a minimum, it needs to be larger than the energy stored in your load's input capacitors.
